# Full-height 3-row sidebar with variable-size middle row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j1tuw3vj/43/ is close to what I'm trying to achieve, but I would like the middle scrollable part (`.scrollable`) to expand to fill the available space--no matter what content is in the top and bottom 'search bar' placeholders, and no matter what height the user's window is.  I.e. the bottom search bar should be flush with the bottom.  What's the best way to achieve this within a Bootstrap context?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Main view, move content down due to fixed navbar. */

.main-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}


/* Container for a sidebar. */

.sidebar-container {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.sidebar-header,
.sidebar-footer {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}


/* Scrollable sidebar. */

.sidebar {
  height: 20%;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.main-view {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav-pills li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-container col-xs-3">
      <div class="sidebar-header">
        <form class="form-inline">
          <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav nav-stacked nav-pills">
            <li>
              <h1>Test</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1>Test</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1>Test</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1>Test</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1>Test</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1>Test</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1>Test</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1>Test</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1>Test</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1>Test1</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1>Test2</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1>Test3</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1>Test4</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1>Test5</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1>Test6</h1>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-footer">
        <form class="form-inline">
          <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-view col-xs-9 pull-right">
      <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Example <span class="text-danger">Text</span>.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really is a specific Bootstrap method for this. I think the best approach would be to make the sidebar a flexbox column.

http://www.codeply.com/go/gRvmeccRbQ

```
/* Container for a sidebar. */
.sidebar-container {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/* Scrollable sidebar. */
.sidebar {
    flex-grow: 1;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use css [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) property for height of sidebar:

```
.sidebar {
 height: calc(100% - 130px);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/ubc6wvhq/1/)

Where 130px is the height of the bottom search box.

Comment: This has a very interesting side effect that no matter what the height in px of the bottom row--even if it's incorrect--this still looks how we want it to.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `display:flex` to achieve this. So your CSS would change to:

```
.sidebar-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;

}

.sidebar {
  display:flex;  
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gurtejsingh/j1tuw3vj/44/

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your CSS to include the following - it positions your second scroll at the bottom of the visible window then leaves the scrolling section to calculate its height according to the remaining visible window height :

```
.sidebar-header {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  height = 100px;
}

.sidebar-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  height = 100px;
}

/* Scrollable sidebar. */
.sidebar {
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: calc(100% - (130px+130px)); 
}
```

Comment: Second scroll?  Why?

Comment: @Kev - I was too hasty - I meant 'search bar'.